# JQplot bar chart [value , description]

Tags: arrays, charts, label, jqplot

I'm using jqplot library and I could use the 'Bar chart'

If I'll want show in display only the description?
Is possible?

Es.
In the first label: value 4000 but show only 'David'.

------------------------------------- David

------------------------------- Tom

------------------------------------------------ Andrew

----------- Mary

```
var arrayValue = [4000,3000,6000,2000];
var arrayDescription = ['David', 'Tom', 'Andrew', 'Mary'];

seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: finRenderer,
    pointLabels: {
        show: true,
        location: 'e',
        edgeTolerance: -25,
        labels: arrayValue
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: So are you saying that currently the labels are the numeric values but you want them to be the descriptions? If so, couldn't you just set `labels` to `arrayDescription` rather than `arrayValue`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would use the `formatString` option:

```
yaxis: {
    tickOptions: { formatString: "$%'.2f" }
}
```

Doing this would render a value of `4000` as `$4,000.00`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I'll want visualize in display only the description? Example 'Tom':

-----------------------------------------------------------Tom \n    
------------------------------------------------- Jack  \n
------------------------------------------David \n

Comment: @Andrea_dev I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify what what you want to do? Also, it might help if you could update your question with your code.